# Left version of \mapsto

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

I there a version of `\mapsto` going from right to left (i.e a "`\leftmapsto`"?
Is there an easy way of creating such a symbol?

Comment: If one doesn't exist, you could make one with the `graphicx` package and `\reflectbox{\mapsto}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX!  For questions like this, there are some very good resources that are in the question linked in Jake's comment above.  To help others find these resources quickly, we'll probably close this question as a duplicate of that one.  This is just to ensure that other people find their way to that "canonical question" as easily as possible.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no link to the other question that this is allegedly a duplicate of, and this question occurs first when I search for this topic.  Is this a compatibility issue or a flaw in the design of the site?

Comment: @Seamus This code didn't compile for me, and the error message seems like garbage. Compiles perfectly without.

Comment: I was looking for a `\mapsfrom` or `\leftmapsto`, and not being able to access either of the required packages from MathJax, I resorted to `\newcommand{\mapsfrom}{\mathrel{\unicode{x21a4}}}`

Answer (score 22):

`\mapsfrom` from the `stmaryrd` package.

You can look up such symbols using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: I tried Detexify but this one didn't come up when I inputted by handwriting (although it does come up when looking up its name).

Answer (score 9):

- `MnSymbol` provides `\leftmapsto`
- `stmaryrd` provides `\mapsfrom`
- with `graphicx` you can create one: `\newcommand\mapsfrom{\mathrel{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{\mapsto}}}}`

Comment: Your command `\mapsfrom` gives the wrong spacing as it is defined.

Comment: That's easily fixed: Just define the command as `\newcommand{\mapsfrom}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{\mapsto}}}}`. The `\mathrel` command tells (La)TeX to treat `\mapsfrom` as a relational operator.

Comment: Fix'd (I hope). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

The [symbols](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) document gives you `\mapsfrom` from the `stmaryrd` package or `\leftmapsto` to from the `MnSymbol` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

%requires stmaryrd
\[ a\mapsfrom x \]

% requires MnSymbol
\[ a\leftmapsto x \]

\end{document}
```

[image]